# How to unmap a project in TFS using eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, tfs

I am trying to unmap a project that I have downloaded while ago from TFS server using Eclipse Plugin for TFS. Needless to say, I can't do that.

When I click on the mapped location, it takes me to the mapped folder and opens the mapped folder on my local hard drive. When I right click on the mapped project, I can't see any option to unmap. These are the options I see:

[image]

(Team Explorer -> Source Control Explorer -> right click on the project)

I tried deleting the directory from my local machine, but I wasn't able to do that either. Is there an easy way to unmap a project in TFS using its Eclipse plugin?

I am using Windows 7 as my operating system. Eclipse Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819.

Comment: Source Control Explorer -> Workspace Dropdown -> Manage Workspaces and edit your workspace mappings.

Comment: Or in Package Explorer, right click on the project, select Team > Manage Workspaces.

Comment: Thanks @EdwardThomson the second one worked for me.

Comment: @EdwardThomson Can you add your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Package Explorer, right click on the Project, navigate to the Team menu and select Manage Workspaces.  Select your workspace, click Edit, and in the manage workspace dialog, remove the appropriate workspace mappings.

Answer (score 0):

By unmapping , if you mean to disconnect from the TFS server and have the code onto your local machine , then you can do this in two ways :

1. ***You can disconnect temporarily(Offline).***
   In Project Explorer , right click on the project directory.
   Go to *Team -> Go Offline.*
   After you are done , you can go to *Team -> Return Online.*
2. ***You can disconnect permanently***
   In Project Explorer , right click on the project directory.
   Go to *Team -> Disconnect project permanently.*
   (this isolates it to your local machine).

I also found these alternate ways as well. Not exaclty sure how it is different , but it works.

1. In TFVC Source Control Explorer , Right click on the project folder.
   Click on remove Mapping.
2. In Project Explorer , right click on the project directory.
   Go to *Team -> Manage Workspaces...*
   Then select your machine from it and press Edit.
    You can see all the active workspace mappings listed there. Remove as required.

**Please note** : I am using eclipse Neon.3 Release(4.6.3).